# NSMutableSet allows adding multiple objects with the same hash

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSObject subclass in which I implemented the `isEqual:` and `hash` methods as follows for testing purposes:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return 1;
}
```

For some reason, I can add multiple objects of this class to an NSMutableSet even though they are the "same".  Is there any reason this would not be working?

---

**Update:** It turns out I was assigning an NSMutableArray instance to an ivar of type NSMutableSet.  D'oh!

Comment: Adding the same object doesn't result in an error, it will just not change the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else in your code that you are not doing right, because overriding methods as you show in the OP causes `NSMutableSet` to recognize my objects as identical:

Test.h:

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
@interface Test : NSObject
@end
```

Test.m:

```
#import "Test.h"
@implementation Test
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return 1;
}
@end
```

main.c:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import "Test.h"
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Test *t1 = [[Test alloc] init];
    Test *t2 = [[Test alloc] init];
    Test *t3 = [[Test alloc] init];
    Test *t4 = [[Test alloc] init];
    NSSet *s = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:t1, t2, t3, t4, nil];
    NSLog(@"%lu", s.count);
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet produces `1`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `addObject` method returns `void` and provides no sort of feedback as to whether or not the item actually got "added".

`- (void)addObject:(id)object`

Are you enumerating the set to determine that the object(s) were "added twice"? Otherwise, what leads you to believe they are?

If two sets were unioned together with `unionSet` should an error occur if both sets contain the same object? Or should the result simply include the same object both original sets included?

What if you were to union a set of exactly one item? Because if you agree with the above, then you'll understand why I say the following...

I think it's just silently swallowing the second `addObject` attempt (the way it's supposed to) and moving on with life.